# beamer frame title with a triangle indicator

Tags: beamer

Is it possible to add a triangle indication on each beamer frame?

e.g.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title here}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-2.5,-2.5) grid (2.5,2.5);
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2cm) node {$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output is below:

[image]

I wish to:

1. add a triangle before "title here" (every frame).
2. add a line below the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible solution -- modify the `frametitle` template.

**Update:** The OP prefers to use the underline cross the whole page so this is how, after modify the `frametitle` template.

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{\vskip4pt
  \leavevmode
%\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}   [wd=\paperwidth,ht=2ex,dp=1ex]{frametitle}%
\underline{\makebox[\paperwidth][l]{\hspace*{40pt}
\large$\blacktriangleright$ {\insertframetitle}}}
\end{beamercolorbox}
%  }%
}
```

[image]

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{\vskip4pt
  \leavevmode
  %\hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2ex,dp=1ex]{frametitle}%
      \hspace*{40pt}        % change this to suit one's need
      \large$\blacktriangleright$ \underline{\insertframetitle}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  %}%
}
```

[image]

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{\vskip4pt
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox} [wd=\paperwidth,ht=2ex,dp=1ex]{frametitle}%
      \hspace*{40pt}
      \large$\blacktriangleright$ \underline{\insertframetitle}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title here}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=.5cm,gray,very thin] (-2.5,-2.5) grid (2.5,2.5);
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2cm) node {$O$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{2nd title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool, but I prefer to use the underline cross the whole page rather than just underline valid text, is it possible?

Comment: How about replace `\underline{\insertframetitle}` in the code  with `\underline{\makebox[0.8\textwidth][l]{\insertframetitle}}`, where makebox is used to wrap the `\insertframetitle1`.

Comment: Or this one, across the whole page --`\underline{\makebox[\paperwidth][l]{\hspace*{40pt}
\large$\blacktriangleright$ {\insertframetitle}}}`